# How to compare two associated column value in three related table in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Students, Friends, and Packages. Students contain two columns: ID and Name. Friends contain two columns: ID and Friend_ID (ID of the ONLY best friend). Packages contain two columns: ID and Salary (offered salary in $ thousands per month)

I have to write a query to output the names of those students whose best friends got offered a higher salary than them. Names must be ordered by the salary amount offered to the best friends. It is guaranteed that no two students got the same salary offer.

Here is my tables:
[Student Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY9rw.png) [Friends Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JXW0.png) [Packges Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7MB4.png)

And the output should like this:[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZljN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join all 3 table with their id while you will get every name with their friend id. Now you have join that friend id with packages id while you will get friends salary. finally filter FRIEND_SALARY>SALARY .
I use oracle syntax here. hope will work fine in mysql also.

```
select TMP2.NAME name 
from (SELECT TMP1.NAME,
       PP.ID,
       TMP1.SALARY salary,
       TMP1.FRIEND_ID,
       PP.SALARY friend_salary
  FROM packages pp,
       (SELECT *
          FROM students s, friends f, packages p
         WHERE S.ID = F.ID 
         AND S.ID = P.ID) tmp1
 WHERE PP.ID = TMP1.FRIEND_ID) tmp2
 where TMP2.FRIEND_SALARY>TMP2.SALARY
```

Comment: I am using MySQL database and when I tried to run the whole query it says ---#1060 - Duplicate column name 'ID'---
at first, I think it was for declaring all ID as primary key then I change it but still, it doesn't work for me.